# People who tell me vs. people telling me

Tags: grammar

I'm wondering if there's any difference, be it semantically, grammatically and so on, between phrases like:

> I hate people telling me what to do. / I hate people who tell me what to do.
>
> They're just a bunch of guys having too much free time / They're just a bunch of guys who have too much free time.
>
> I have a soft spot for girls wearing skirts. / I have a soft spot for girls who wear skirts.

Answer (score 1):

> people telling ...

puts the accent on the verb you want to underline.

> people who tell ...

puts the accent on the people.

Comment: Yes. _I hate people telling me what to do_ = _I hate being told what to do_. // _I hate people who tell me what to do_ = _I hate those people who tell me what to do_.

Comment: The two other sentences aren't charged with enought feeling to have a very different meaning but I would say as follow: `guys having too much free time` = "it's ok, they have too much free time after hard work" // `guys who have too much free time` = "those guys have really too much free time, they are wasting their youth !". I can't find special difference on the last sentence

Comment: So how does one break down the other sentences in this way and are they all equally correct?

Comment: On the last one I would say (with exaggeration): `for girls wearing skirts` = "_for girls who have some skirts_" // `for girls who wear skirts` = "_for girls who nearly only wear skirts_" (associated maybe with negative class bias...)